# Docker multi-stage for Flask + VueJs project

Tags: python, docker, vue.js, flask, docker-compose

I have a project with Flask as backend and VueJS for frontend. Want to put all in the container, which will run on production server.

I need to install all dependencies (`npm install`) and build my static files from vue (`npm run build`) to get **dist** folder (with HTML file and assets), then build Flask project: install python, dependencies and run the server on gunicorn. After that copy my **dist** folder to Flask directory.

I'm read about multi-stage and try to combine it, here is my Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine as backend-builder
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
RUN cd ..
RUN ls
RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM busybox
COPY --from=build-stage /frontend/dist /app/dist
RUN ls
```

It's going but don't copy **dist** to Flask directory

My project structure is:

```
project_folder
 - app (python + flask files)
   -- app.py
   -- wsgi.py
   -- requirements.txt
   -- etc
 - frontend (vuejs files, packages)
   -- public
   -- src
   -- package.json
   -- etc
 - Dockerfile
```

What i'm doing wrong? How to write Dockerfile, to solve my problem?

Comment: These might help in structuring your Dockerfile, Dockerizing flask app: https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application as well as looking into Dockerizing Vue.js app: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html

Comment: Your Dockerfile could be improved/simplified (in particular `RUN cd ..` is a no-op, and `RUN mkdir /frontend` is unnecessary given this is implied by `WORKDIR /frontend`)

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM busybox` line creates a new image, it doesn't reference the python image. Would just build the js before you build the python so that you can copy the files in when the python build is complete.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
RUN cd ..
RUN ls
RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM python:3.7-alpine as backend-builder
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY --from=build-stage /frontend/dist /app/dist
```